# mysql return duplicate records based on same key used in IN CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID IN (41,41)
```

I need it to return the product record twice due to limitations with the application code.

I am not too familiar with SQL so really stuck, I don't want to run single queries for each product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it appear twice, you can do:

```
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID IN (41)
UNION ALL
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID IN (41)
```

What the [`UNION`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator) operator does is it essentially "tacks" the result of one query onto the result of *another*... so in your case, we are "tacking" on the *same* exact selection so that all rows are duplicated twice in your final result.

---

However, what you'll probably want to do for more complex queries is use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID 
FROM PRODUCT P 
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN ...
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT NULL UNION ALL 
    SELECT NULL
) cj
WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID IN (41) AND ... AND ... AND ..
```

This way, rows will be duplicated as many times as there are `SELECT NULL`'s within the `CROSS JOIN` subselect, and the `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions of the main query only need to be executed once.

The nice thing about using [`CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) is that you don't need to evaluate a join condition, it simply makes a Cartesian product between two sets of data.

Simply tack on the `CROSS JOIN` at the end of all of your main `JOIN` operations to manually duplicate your data.

Comment: thanks, that worked. The query I posted was a simplified one, the actual one has joins with three tables and 5 clauses in the where statement. If I do a union the whole query needs to be duplicated as many times as number of products. Is there much overhead of doing the union?

Answer (score 3):

Try this::

```
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID=41
UNION ALL
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT P WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID=41
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. The query I posted was a simplified one, the actual one has joins with three tables and 5 clauses in the where statement. If I do a union the whole query needs to be duplicated as many times as number of products. Is there much overhead of doing the union?

Answer (score 1):

Another way (using `UNION ALL` in an internal level). Easier to combine with complex queries (as you mention in the comments):

```
SELECT p.price, p.product_id
FROM 
        PRODUCT AS p 
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT 41 AS product_id
        UNION ALL
          SELECT 41
        ) AS selection
      ON p.product_id = selection.product_id ;
```

Comment: You are technically still using `UNION ALL` ;)

Answer (score 0):

A cartesian product (vary similar to a cross-join):

```
SELECT P.PRICE, P.PRODUCT_ID
FROM FROM PRODUCT P
JOIN (values(1),(2) ) AS two ON 1=1
WHERE P.PRODUCT_ID IN (42)
        ;
```